# PDF created by PDF4Net missing fields

Tags: pdf

Does anyone have any idea about this? I modified a pdf file by adding a PDFPushButtonField in PDF4NET. I can see it in Safari or Chrome in windows 7 system. But when I open it in IPAD Safari browser, the button I added is missing.

Comment: I work for the company that develops PDF4NET. Please send your question to our support and they will help you. Please include the input PDF file, output PDF file and the code you used to modify the file.

Comment: Can you tell me your supposrt's email so I can attach the input and output PDF files? Thanks.

Comment: techsupport at o2sol.com